# Odd-YTD Expression Filter

Tags: filter, calendar, expression, calculation, cognos

I have a report in which I am applying a YTD filter. Instead of utilizing a normal YTD filter from Jan - Dec, the report needs to capture dates that start mid-year and ends the following mid-year.

For Example: 9/1/2022 through 8/31/23. -> this I have achieved!

Ideally, I'd like to get this report on an auto-scheduling basis that grabs data from current year (Starting in Sept) through August 31 of following calendar years.

Example: 9/1/2023 through 8/31/24 where the current and future year auto calculates based on previous years Sept - August requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Create 2 new data items in the query like this...

From date =

```
date(concat(trim(cast(extract(year,current_date) as varchar(10))),'-09-01'))
```

To Date =

```
_last_of_month (date(concat(trim(cast((extract(year,current_date) + 1) as varchar(10))),'-08-01')))
```

The filter for the query would be:

```
[Invoice Date] between [From Date] and [To Date]
```